# Using DOMDocument in Zendframework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, domdocument

I would like to use DOMDocument in ZendFramework 2 but I don't know how. My normal script (non-zf2) looks as follows:

```
<?php 
...
$response = $client->$webservice($variables);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response->$property);
return $dom;
```

And it works fine. But I want to use this in my ZendFramework 2 Application. But this line:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
```

gives me this error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Sols\Model\DOMDocument' not found in...
I thought mayby I should use Zend\Dom\Query but that won't work either. How to be able to use the "standard" DOMDocument in ZendFramework2?

By the way, DOMDocument works fine on my server (if I don't use it within ZendFramework2)...

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: try `$dom = new \DOMDocument();`

Comment: `Zend_Dom_Query`is just a thin wrapper around DOMDocument that provides W3 Selectors.

Comment: Oops, forgot the backslash... thank you l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè !